# sending payload for post method in VBA

Tags: vba, api

I'm trying to login to a website using VBA Excel, but I'm having trouble to send payload post method like in python request.
Example in python

```
def login():
    s = requests.Session()
    payload = {
        'username':sett.username,
        'password':sett.password1
    }
    res = s.post(link, json=payload)
    ref_t = json.loads(res.content)['content']['refresh_token']
    t = json.loads(res.content)['content']['token']
    return t
```

this is what I've tried but fail:

```
Dim request As New WinHttpRequest
request.Open "POST", auth_url, False
auth = "username=" & user & "," & "password=" & pass
request.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
request.SetCredentials "username:" & user, "password:" & pass, 0
request.Send auth
    
If request.Status <> 200 Then
    MsgBox request.ResponseText
    Exit Sub
End If
```

the response text shows "Username is required, but was not received", "Password is required, but was not received", "code":400.

Edit:

```
Dim auth As New Dictionary

auth.Add "username", user
auth.Add "password", pass


request.Open "POST", auth_url, False
request.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"
request.Send JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(auth)
```

Comment: It looks like it is expecting a JSON payload which `auth` doesn't look like the proper format. It will probably be something like `auth = "{""username"":""" & user & """password"":""" & pass & """}"` (untested) and remove `request.SetCredentials "username:" & user, "password:" & pass, 0`

Comment: I still have the same response, do you have any other idea?

Comment: Not really but 1 thing I'll check is that `auth` is in a proper JSON format, try `Debug.Print auth` and copy/paste the output in Immediate window to a JSON parser to confirm that its format is correct. [I use this parser usually](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Comment: I tried to use parser also and it matches the payload I see in google devtools: {"username":"abc@def.com","password":"1234567890"}, but still failed to deliver the username and password

Comment: Which external reference(s) or library are you using ? https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON ?

Comment: @iDevlop yes indeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I need to use SetRequestHeader
Edit:

```
Dim auth As New Dictionary

auth.Add "username", user
auth.Add "password", pass


request.Open "POST", auth_url, False
request.SetRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json"
request.Send JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(auth)
```